# RabbitMQ plugin to remove duplicate messages

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a RabbitMQ queues for documents generation. Basically, each document has `type` and `state` (new, processing, ready), so I use topic exchange with routing keys like `type.state`. Every time document changes I send the message with last document description to the exchange and it works good enough.

However sometimes document can be processed twice:

1. User send new document. So new message `report.new` is sent to exchange.
2. While worker hasn't started document processing (the queue hasn't yet reached) user updated the document. The new message `report.new` for the same document is sent.
3. So now worker get the first message and start his work, while the document was changed and so this work is totally senseless.

For now I'm just add small code into workers, comparing `last_modified` document key from the message with the one from the database and ack the message if they are not the same. However I don't think this is the best solution.

My idea is to add `ID` to message headers and have some RabbitMQ plugin which will remove older messages with the same `ID` from the queue.

Thanks.

P.S. Maybe another MQ engine can be useful here? E.g. maybe ActiveMQ has such a feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i've read about RabbitMQ inner architecture and find out it's impossible. So the way around for somebody looking for it.

1. Send only document `ID` in message body
2. Create a key-value store for worker (i use memcached for this). Key is `ID` value is timestamp of last worker run for this `ID`.
3. When worker receives the message it checks if message timestamp greater then the one from key-value store. If it is, then update timestamp in the store and run the task, otherwise just skip it.

Comment: Memcache is not great for this as it could drop your key/value without warning.

Comment: 1) is the key/value store placed before your exchange/ queue ? 
2) What if i'm writing from multiple producers and don't want duplicates between them ?

Comment: @eranotzap Didn't get your first question. Regarding the second one, it doesn't matter, because deduplication is done on the receiving stage. And 472084 is totally right about his comment, it's better to use Redis or smth.

Comment: @Ximik what if i wanted to remove duplicates on the sending side. is it something that is supported natively in the exchange ?

Meaning i don't want to send duplicates to the client. I have a constant stream and a redundancy stream i want to send only from one of them. 
and one might miss an event that the other was missing so i wan't to fill in the gaps

Comment: @eranotzap I think, it's impossible. These days, there is Kafka which provide somehow similar feature (but still, not exactly you're trying to achieve). See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction However you can still have duplicates. Moreover it's not an MQ, but really more like a stream.

Answer (score 7):

You can check this [plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) I wrote which allows to de-duplicate messages published within the broker.

You can de-duplicate on the exchange or at the queue according to your needs. Only thing your publisher needs to do is to set the `x-deduplicate-message` message header with the `ID` of your message.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it doesn't enqueue a duplicate message. The question, I guess, is about enqueuing the new message, and removing the previous duplicated one.

Comment: True, removing old-messages in RMQ is a non-trivial problem and I'd suggest a different queueing system if that is a critical requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, [ActiveMQ has "duplicate message detection"](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/duplicate-detection.html), but it works differently. It does not remove old message from the queue but it does not add new message to it instead. So it works the same as [plugin for RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50286672/2988107).