# Publishing an Event to a Single Microservice Instance

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I'm working on a project that has several event-driven microservices and also using Kubernetes for load balancing. All the services are both publishers and listeners. When a microservice publishes an event, all the listeners are catching the event (if it listens that specific event) and doing their job. There was no problem with this flow until this:

Let's say I have a microservice responsible for sending e-mails. And this service is duplicated 2 times by the load balancer due to high load. Now we have 3 instances of e-mail service. When a "sendMail" event is published, all the 3 instances are catching the event and sending an e-mail for their own. At the end of the day 3 e-mail are being sent.

My question is, can I configure a cloud bus that allows me to publish events for both scenarios. I want to say to an event "when a single listener catches you, disappear" or "go to every listener waiting out there".

For example;

Microservices: A, B, C

Duplicated by load balancer: A1, A2, A3, B1...

Case 1: I want to publish an event for all the services' instances.

Case 2: I want to publish an event for service A instances.

Case 3: I want to publish an event for a single instance of A (don't 
care which).

I have tried;
Giving destinations to events, but all the instances have same bus name since they are duplicated as same. If I give/know a single instance bus name, I wouldn't use it because that pod might die.

Event publishing;

```java
applicationContext().publishEvent(
        new customEvent(
                this,  // Source
                busProperties().getId(),  // Origin Service
                null  // Destination Service (null: all)
        )
);
```

Event listener;

```java
@Component
public class Listener implements ApplicationListener<CustomEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomEvent event) {
        Foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using as this ***bus*** ? KubeMQ?

Comment: **RabbitMQ** but I don't want to solve this as RabbitMQ specific, I'm looking for a solution at framework level.

Comment: I see, you can include a secondary message-acknowledgment topic, where any listener would immediately publish its own listening happening event with some message id. Though this is risky, there will be race conditions, and in case some service restarts, it will go ahead and read the past messages, you might need to store these read message id's in some cache maybe? It becomes very messy to replace an already existing feature in all brokers (I think)

Comment: Or you can extract the `listener` module as a separate ***single*** service, and feed the the read messages to A,B,C in a round robin manner maybe?

Comment: I feel there has to be a property/config that specifies the events are being removed when a single listener consumes them. That would solve my problem easily. But if I can't find it I don't want any messy solutions. I already can publish an event as P2P with autowired RabbitTemplate, I think I might use this solution that I don't want but also not messy.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541347/3641067), you can move to kafka maybe, it has the support for multiple consumers without duplication, it has offset metadata to track the latest read message for each topic for each consumer.

Comment: I have a similar case in my application and I moved to Redis to solve this problem. Messages are stored in a List and removed from there as soon as they're read.

Comment: I want to make this clear, I also use duplicated events for each instance as well. So I want to do the both as I explained at case 1/2/3. There are several state events and all services and their instances must catch and update themselves. Thanks for the comments by the way, I will check Kafka and Redis as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and implemented a partial solution, using Spring Cloud Stream along side with Spring Cloud Bus. I'm using Cloud Stream with custom queues and groups for single events (sentMail event for the first example). When I send a message through Cloud Stream and if multiple instances of a microservice are listening the message, they receive it one by one like this:

Sending messages: M1, M2, M3

Listening A microservice instances: A1, A2

With Cloud Bus:

A1 receives M1, M2, M3

A2 receives M1, M2, M3

With Cloud Stream (custom groups defined):

A1 receives M1, M3

A2 receives M2

For implementation: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream

Answer (score 1):

I understand better now, Here is the [Image Link](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/56894e581c1210fead06f878/1532295877340-V08C7VRC02TR94J303GM/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kJMyHperWZxre3bsQoFNoPhZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWEtT5uBSRWt4vQZAgTJucoTqqXjS3CfNDSuuf31e0tVGDclntk9GVn4cF1XFdv7wlNvED_LyEM5kIdmOo2jMRZpu3E9Ef3XsXP1C_826c-iU/KafkaPubSub.png?format=500w) i posted earlier. I'm sure you already know about it. It is a common issue and the best way is to use a redis acting as a "[blocking](https://redis.io/commands/brpop)" mechanism. Since the message queue is sending requests asynchronously to all the consumers, we will not know who is receiving and processing the request but we are ensure that it isn't processed by all by using blocking. Before doing any operation, check for the block and if it doesn't exist, process the request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be solved by setting your consumerGroupId. Each instance of your application(each microservice of email service) needs to have a unique groupId so that rabbitmq will send request to any one of those available unique groups.

[Here is how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXjyf.png)

Comment: Firstly, the image you shared is not available, could you check it? (It maybe blocked by my company's network policy, I don't know). I was mentioning this solution with my las sentence. Let's say we have 3 instances of A (A1, A2, A3) and each instances have their own groupId. You say I must publish an event by giving a specific groupId. For example A1, but what happens if A1 service pod dies? If A1 dies, A2 or A3 should catch the event and do the necessary work, this is why I cannot give a fixed bus name. Pods are constantly/eventually dying, restarting due to some problems or version updates.